# Convert String to Float Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to convert String into Float or int in PineScript?

We can use `str.tostring` to convert float to string, but is there a way to go from string to float or int?

I want to try this as a workaround to offset value to the left. As I cant find a way to offset a value to the left, only to the right, I would like to see If I can achieve it by going from Float to String in July/2021 and from String to Float in May/2021.

Answer (score 8):

There is a built-in function for that in Pine v5. See [str.tonumber()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_str%7Bdot%7Dtonumber)
It was also already there in Pine v4. See [tonumber()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_tonumber)